# Why is that question too broad?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, specific-question, too-broad

I don't understand what the following question got closed as too broad. It simply asks for some studies on a specific question. Since no close voter left a comment regarding the "too broad" issue, I am asking here.

---

[Research studies covering the reasons why faculty applicants accept or reject academic jobs?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/72300/452)

> Is there any research/study/survey that tried to quantify the reasons why faculty applicants accepted or rejected academic jobs that have been proposed to them? (e.g., location, salary, the current faculty, college ranking)
>
> I am mostly interested in the United States and the field of computer science, but curious about other countries and fields as well.

[image]

Comment: In case you were wondering about the vote breakdown: you may know already that the "put on hold" box shows the [majority close reason](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54917/distinguish-close-votes-by-reason) even if it's not unanimous. For this post, however, all five close votes cite the "too broad" reason.

Comment: @ff524 Thanks, yes that's annoying, this is one of the reasons why I avoid throwing close votes.

Answer (score 2):

A key reason that I voted to close is that the question did not show evidence of research, per Bill Barth's comment.  This is an incredibly broad topic, and as the help page says:

> Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.

Did you try plugging in some related terms on Google Scholar, like Bill suggested? It certainly seemed to me that there were some useful possibilities in the literature that came back from a simple keyword search. If you didn't find that literature useful, what was unsatisfying to you about the results that came back?  That might help narrow things down enough to be meaningfully reopened.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the title 'what are the reasons why faculty applicants accept or reject academic jobs' is too broad to be answerable in the SE format, however, the question asked by Franck 'is there research study that determines why applicants accept or reject academic position that have been proposed to them' is quite answerable. I have edited the title to be more specific, and I suggest the question to be re-opened.